# Trouble making queries in ForeignKey fields in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to make a query to find the number or Charging lots with a certain Charge Type in a Charging Station.

Models

```
class ChargeType(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField('Charging speed', max_length=15)
    current = models.BooleanField('Default AC, Check for DC')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class ChargeStation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    address =   models.TextField()description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ChargeLot(models.Model):
    charge_type = models.ForeignKey(ChargeType, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='chargetype')
    charge_station = models.ForeignKey(ChargeStation, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.charge_type.type
```

I tried

`from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg`

`chargelot=ChargeLot.objects.all()`

`ChargeStation.objects.annotate(level=ArrayAgg('chargelot__charge_type__level'))`

But it returns a FieldError saying chargelot is not one of the choices available.

**How can get all the charge levels of ChargeLots in one ChargeStation?** Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
from django.db.models import Avg
ChageLot.objects.values('charge_type__level').annotate(count=Avg('charge_type__level'))
```